# I want to create new object in Hashmap and add extracted month to that object

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to create a list of month which extracts its month from date of the transaction. But i am not able to create new object in hashmap to add month and assign the value of extracted month to that object.

Maybe my question is not too clear since i haven't properly understood Hashmap. So, I  need help understanding Hashmap properly

```
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class TransactionAnalysis {
        public HashMap<String, MonthAnalysis> monthAnalysis;
        public List<Transaction> transactionList;

            public TransactionAnalysis(){
                this.monthAnalysis = new HashMap<>();
                this.transactionList = new LinkedList<>();
            }

            private String getMonth(String strDate){
                long date = Long.parseLong(strDate);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM");
                return sdf.format(new Date(date));
            }

            public void addTransaction(Transaction transaction){

        if (Util.isValid(transaction.amount) && Util.isValid(transaction.type)) {
            transactionList.add(transaction);
            // find the month in which the transaction happened
            String month = getMonth(transaction.date);
            // In month analysis see if the months exists
            if(monthAnalysis.containsKey(month)){
                MonthAnalysis monthData = monthAnalysis.get(month);

            }else{
                monthAnalysis.put(month, new monthData);
                //MonthAnalysis monthData = monthAnalysis.computeIfAbsent(month, m -> new MonthAnalysis());
            }

            // If it doesnt exist, create a new month correspoding to the transaction date
            // The key for the month analysis hash should be YYYYMM
            // check if the transaction is debit or credit
            // if it is credit, in monthly analysis make it credit
            if(transaction.type=="Credit") {
                monthData.credit += Long.parseLong(transaction.type);
            } else {
                monthData.debit += Long.parseLong(transaction.type);
            }
            // monthData.credit += transaction.credit
            // if it is debit ..


        }

    }

    public List<Transaction> getTransactionList(){
        return this.transactionList;
    }

    public HashMap<String, MonthAnalysis> getMonthAnalysis() {
        return this.monthAnalysis;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: To understand hashmap: try your favorite search engine. This is not a secret conspiracy theory that only lives in the shades. That stuff is documented a zillion times out there.

Comment: Code looks fine to me. Hashmap can't have duplicate keys... Is that the problem?

Comment: I am having trouble in assigning month value in hashmap in "else" statement.

Comment: what trouble? You can't compile the code or what?

Comment: Your question is unclear, but I suspect you are having trouble with the scope of your monthData variable—in which case your problem can be solved by replacing that innermost if/else statement with `MonthAnalysis monthData = monthAnalysis.computeIfAbsent(month, m -> new MonthAnalysis());`.

Comment: I think "month" is key here. My 2nd "if" statement checks whether that month is already there in hashmap or not. If it is then i have to associate two values with it (credit and debit). If the month is not there in hashmap then i want to create a new key ( month name) and associate credit and debit values related to that month.